# error 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, windows-8.1

[image]This is 2nd day I'm spending on this sql server problem! long story short, I have downloaded/installed sql server 2014 express version on my windows 8.1 operating system. sql server works fine however when I get in it and create tables or etc, when I run asp.net (mvc 4) and click on login page or register page it throws following error:

*error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.*

I have searched in stackoveflow and also msdn, few other forums but did not find a specific and solution to nail this down.

on my machine I have:

**SQL SERVER (MSSQLSERVER) service running (Automatic)
Microsoft LocalDB is installed**

However, 
SQL Server Browser stopped
SQL Server Agent   stopped

every time I am trying to restart or start them I get this message:

*The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled device associated with it[0x80070422]*

I also tried this solution but it didn't help. please see this URL

http://www.aspneter.com/2013/08/error-50-local-database-runtime-error-occurred/

Can this be something in web.config?

any help will be appreciated greatly.

Thanks.
amit

Comment: Can you access SQL Server using SSMS? If so, create a new database using SSMS, and update the connection string in web.config instead of using LocalDB.

Comment: @Win I will give it a try and will update you on that. Thanks.

Comment: it says: "Unable to add data connection. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: It seems (not sure yet) I'm missing a Sql Server 2014 component such as Microsoft.SqlServer.Manangement.Sdk.Sfc which is a component DLL for SMO assemblies. I guess should be able to download it from MSDN site. let's see!

Comment: Solution: Ok the problem is resolved by downloading Microsoft SQL Server 2012 SP1 Feature Pack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem is resolved by downloading [Microsoft SQL Server 2012 SP1 Feature Pack.
Service Pack SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35580)